# Why do ref locals have to be assigned at the point of declaration?

Tags: c#, cil, ref

Continuing my journey into ref locals I've found another restriction I don't understand the reason for, and that is *ref locals have  to be definitely assigned **at the point of declaration***.

I get why you can't initialize it with a reference to a variable that's not definitely assigned, as that would require the compiler to somehow tie the assignment statuses of both the variable and the ref local.

```
object variable;
ref object reference = ref variable;
variable = new object();
// Now `reference` should be definitely assigned, 
// so the compiler would have to work some magic to recognize that.
```

But why is this illegal:

```
object variable = new object();
ref object reference;
reference = ref variable;
```

Couldn't the compiler just treat `reference` as any other not definitely assigned variable? It's even weirder, because since C# 7.3 you can reassign ref locals, but this particular restriction is still left in. Does having an uninitialized reference break IL in some way? Is it somehow unsafe to allow such a variable to exist? Or would lifting this restriction be theoretically possible, but very hard/not worth the time?

Comment: I believe that is another case of ["we must never allow an alias to a dead variable"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42876328/11683).

Comment: Agreed, allowing reassignment should allow them to drop the 7.0 rule.  Hard to analyze the aliasing implications, the compiler change was probably substantial.  It would probably all look different if it wasn't done agile, some odds that a future version changes the rule again.

Comment: I suggest closing this as a duplicate of GSerg's link.